# Specify top/bottom color of a shade style in TiKz

Tags: tikz-styles

I just want to modify the color of a shaded node. In the docu I found only an example of `right color=...;left color=...`.

But per default the color of a shaded node goes vertical. And I don't want to change that.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [
        mynode/.style={
            shade, % top/bottom color?
            align=center},
        every node/.style=mynode
    ]
    \node {X};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ...there is a spurious "S" at the start of MWE (can't edit, less then 6 chars) ;-)

Comment: @Rmano Thanks. (It lets me do a 1 char edit, apparently.)

Comment: @cfr difference in reputation. :). 2,000 is required I think.

Comment: @Rmano You see the things you have to look forward to if Alenanno is right? ;)

Comment: @Alenanno ^^^^^^

Comment: To check what you can do and can't do (yet), go to `tex.stackexchange.com/privileges`, or any other site. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look in TikZ manual, you will find in chapter 65 Shading Library (from page 686 further) description of shadings. For color you have possibilities

- shading axis

  - `top color= ...`, `bottom color=...` and  `middle color=...`
  - `left color=...`, `right color=...` and `midle color` (the same as above)

and

- shading ball
- shading billinear transformation
- etc

So in your case:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [
        mynode/.style={
            shade, 
            top color=blue, bottom color=red, 
            align=center},
        every node/.style=mynode
    ]
    \node {X};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So, it is worth to read manual (one pictures doesn't show all possibilities :-) )

Comment: You could specify that the middle color, in both instances, must be set last.

Comment: As I (implicit)  mentioned in my answer ...

Answer (score 4):

An image worth 1 thousand words...

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [
        mynode/.style={
            shade, % top/bottom color?
            right color=blue, left color=red, shading angle=0,
            align=center},
        every node/.style=mynode
    ]
    \node {X};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```